# Helm delele is hanging indefinitely

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I run `helm ls --all` and get

```
NAME    REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS  CHART               NAMESPACE
assets  1           Fri Aug 18 15:34:12 2017    DELETED elasticsearch-0.1.9 default
```

Then I run `helm del --purge assets` and it hangs indefinitely.

The `tiller` pod log moves when I run the `ls` command, but doesn't move when I run the `del` command.

I tried deleting the tiller pod to get a fresh one, but the problem remained.

This is the script I used to deploy Elasticsearch in case it helps:

```
echo "deploying Elasticsearch cluster"
helm init
helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator
helm install incubator/elasticsearch --name assets --set data.resources.limits.cpu=250m,data.resources.limits.memory=1024Mi,data.resources.requests.cpu=250m,data.resources.requests.memory=1024Mi
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you have any post install hook that is causing this failure, for helm v3 you can use

`helm uninstall <Releasename> -n <Namespace> --no-hooks`

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I finally got some feedback from the `tiller` logs:

```
uninstall: Failed deletion of "assets": timed out waiting for "assets-elasticsearch-data" to be synced
```

After a very long wait and a few restarts of the tiller pod, the delete command worked. So the answer to my initial question is:

**Helm can't delete a deployment when not all of its components are synced.**

As for why a component was not synced, it's still not clear.